# Simple Graph Does Not Represent Data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This is a very straightforward question. I have and x axis of years and a y axis of  numbers increasing linearly by 100. When plotting this with pandas and matplotlib I am given a graph that does not represent the data whatsoever. I need some help to figure this out because it is such a small amount of code:

The CSV is as follows:

```
A,B
2012,100
2013,200
2014,300
2015,400
2016,500
2017,600
2018,700
2012,800
2013,900
2014,1000
2015,1100
2016,1200
2017,1300
2018,1400
```

The Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("CSV/DSNY.csv")

data.set_index("A", inplace=True)


data.plot()
plt.show()
```

The graph this yields is:

[image: graph from CSV data]

It is clearly very inconsistent with the data - any suggestions?

Comment: It absolutely represents the data. Is `A` a string?

Comment: The time axis (A) data isn't monotonic....it jumps from 2018 back to 2012, and takes on a different set of B values.  You could try sorting the data points in time order, but the plot would still look weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behaviour of matplotlib/pandas is to draw a line between successive data points, and not to mark each data point with a symbol.

**Fix:** change `data.plot()` to `data.plot(style='o')`, or `df.plot(marker='o', linewidth=0)`.

Result:
[image: result of style='o']

Answer (score 1):

All you need is sort A before plotting.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("CSV/DSNY.csv").reset_index()
data = data.sort_values('A')
data.set_index("A", inplace=True)


data.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This produces a sawtooth pattern with vertical segments that may not be what OP is looking for. I think the solution is to suppress the line and add a marker symbol with `df.plot(style='o')`.